# Samsung s23 ultra/google activity/google account

Tags: google-account

I have alot of weird and unexplainable activities on my google activity. Apps I haven't opened in months showing up. Activity i actually did showing up hours after the fact in middle of night while I sleep. It shows me using Google meet at 4 in the morning in the middle of a work week. Those are just to name a very few.

Also in my google account my phone was showing up twice under devices but just by the model number?

There is so much thats been happening that it's concerning. None of my bank accounts have been touched or hacked. But it's like someone else is doing stuff in the background and I don't know how to explain any of it. Has anyone else had any problems like this at all?

Comment: Did you ask a similar question as a different user?

Comment: Related about someone with similar issue recently: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/256071/44325

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about it then just change the password.  To me, it sounds more like multiple devices are on the same account.  Perhaps your friend, partner on an older phone.

Other measures

- Use face recognition or fingerprint on the phone
- Install a virus scanner such as Kaspersky (the free version does a good job)
- Install an Applock app, so that certain apps (such as banking) require one more step/password